# Bulk Insert several errors

Tags: bulkinsert

Im trying to upload 1000 txt files into one table un SQL. I'm using the following query, to upload one txt file at a time:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].test1
( 
    [Division] varchar(50) null,
    [Factura] varchar(50) null,
    [Fecha Factura] varchar(50) null,
    [Inicio Período] varchar(50) null,
    [Fin Período] varchar(50) null,
    [Tipo de Factura] varchar(50) null,
    [Cuenta Contrato] varchar(50) null,
    [Tipo de Cliente] varchar(50) null,
    [Servicio Facturado] varchar(50) null,
    [Porción] varchar(50) null,
    [Unidad de Lectura] varchar(50) null,
    [Tipo de Consumo] varchar(50) null,
    [Concepto Facturado] varchar(50) null,
    [Consumo Facturado] varchar(50) null,
    [Importe Facturado] varchar(50) null,
    [Importe CCAR] varchar(50) null
)


BULK INSERT [dbo].test1
    FROM '\\dataserver\SQL Data Files\SQL_EMELIZ\FC x Bloque Detallada\201308 Detalle Facturas\FACT_BLOQ_AGO13 (1).txt'
    WITH 
    ( 
                FIELDTERMINATOR = ';', 
        ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A' 
    )
```

but gives this error message:

> Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 22 Bulk load: An unexpected end of
>   file was encountered in the data file. Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 22 The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported
>   an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>   Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 22 Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB
>   provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I just ran this one:

bulk insert [dbo].AAA_2013_2015
from '\\dataserver\SQL Data Files\SQL_EMELIZ\FC x Bloque Detallada\201308 Detalle Facturas\FACT_BLOQ_AGO13 (4).txt'
 with (firstrow = 2,
  lastrow = ???,
  fieldterminator = ';', 
  rowterminator = '0x0A')

and work putting the last row as 10, however this is not true.  All the files does not have the same amount of rows, is there a way that the system recognize something like lastrow = allrows -1...I need the penultimate row.

Comment: It sounds a bit familiar, do you have  an empty row at the end of the file? try removing it by using backspace.

Comment: @Remco
no, the data at the end look like this:[Residencial;Agua;5/8";39;45395855;E;BLOQUE 2;2.15;4.28;6.65
045;204030344271;20130827;20130621;20130821;PF;000021619066;Residencial;Agua;5/8";39;45395855;E;BLOQUE 1;3.17;3.96;0.00
Fecha de registro Desde/Hasta: 08/01/2013 a 08/31/2013. Total de registros transferidos al archivo: 1971689]
i dont need the data from Fecha de Registro...on beyond

Comment: The double quote character in your data file looks fishy to me. Isn't it escaping the rest of the semicolons of that row? Have you tried to remove the double quote?

Comment: @LittleSanti what do you mean by double quote?